# Regex digit range in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, regex

I need create SQl query with REGEXP function.

I need find serialize fields in (for example):

```
a:2:{s:5:"rooms";i:2;s:5:"area";i:4;}
a:2:{s:5:"rooms";i:2;s:5:"area";i:7;}
a:2:{s:5:"rooms";i:2;s:5:"area";i:18;}
```

Where "area" value can be:

```
1-5 or 5-10 or 10-20 or 20-50 or 50-100
```

I try use REGEXP `.*"area";i:[1-5].*` for first condition (1-5), but it shows wrong data. For other conditions also сan't make up.

Comment: When you say "value can be: 1-5", do you mean a digit between `1` and `5` or literally the value `1-5`?

Comment: Yes, 1-5 is from 1 to 5.

Comment: Can you provide one test case. Input and output @AlexFreeman

Comment: @AlexFreeman . . . Why would you store values in such a JSON-like way and then use string functions to parse them?

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex should cover for your area value with your expectations:

```
("area";i:(?:(?!0)\d{1,2}|100)\b)
```

Here is the regex101 link : [Link Here](https://regex101.com/r/Wgxjxo/1/)

Comment: Thank you, but i need decisions for 5 conditions.

Comment: Hi i guess all this conditions you mentioned above are covered in this regex.If i am understanding it right these are your arequirements.
Value should not begin 0. which will validated by (?!0)
And you have to check values from 1-100 if it occurs and not more than that.